# What does POSSVit mean in this latin inscription that appears in a novel?

Tags: vocabulary

What does POSSVit mean in this latin inscription that appears in a novel?
hi. does anyone know in machen's "great god pan" the latin inscription that is supposed to appear on a Roman monument which says
"DEVOMNODENTi
FLAvIVSSENILISPOSSVit
PROPTERNVPtias
quaSVIDITSVBVMBra"
what does POSSVit mean? posit? i cannot find it in https://www.online-latin-dictionary.com/ or wiktionary any article for anything close to it.

Answer (score 7):

> DEVOMNODENTi FLAvIVSSENILISPOSSVit PROPTERNVPtias quaSVIDITSVBVMBra

I'm guessing these are separate lines, since we've got several words joined together on each one. Separating them out would give:

> Devo M(?) Nodenti
> Flavius Senilis possuit
> propter nuptias
> quas vidit sub umbra

This is pretty close to an actual inscription [to the god Nodens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodens), CIL 07 00137:

> D(eo) M(arti) N(odenti) T(itus) Flavius Senilis pr(aepositus) rel(igionis?) ex stipibus pos{s}uit o(pitu)lante Victorino interp(re)tiante
> *To the god Mars Nodens, Titus Flavius Senilis, superintendent of the cult, had (this mosaic) laid from the offerings with assistance from Victorinus the interpreter*

The braces around the {s} in pos{s}uit here mean that the editor thinks the original author made a mistake. There's not supposed to be a second S there: the word should be *posuit*, "he placed".

Taking that as our guide, we get something like:

> De{v}o M[arti] Nodenti
> *For the god Mars Nodens*
> Flavius Senilis pos{s}uit
> *Flavius Senilis laid [this inscription]*
> propter nuptias
> *on account of the marriage*
> quas vidit sub umbra
> *that he saw beneath the shadow.*

I would expect *sub umbr**is*** instead of *umbr**a***, under the "shadows" instead of under the "shadow", but I don't know anything about this novel; perhaps a single shadow makes more sense in context.

Comment: But *sub umbrā* is valid form for singular number ("beneath shadow"), while *sub umbrīs* is form for plural number ("beneath shadows")... (I think that you can just update English translation.)

Comment: @Arfrever Ahh, of course. I was thinking _sub umbris_ is more common, so they must have changed the case; I completely missed that they could have just changed the number.

Comment: Of possible interest: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodens (note there are several inscriptions to Nodens cited there).